# Android XML fragment tag resize programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, resize

Can I change the size of a fragment, added in the XML by using code? If so, how?

This is how the fragment view is inflated:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sigiture);
        init();
        setMetrics();

        Log.d("Layout Width", "" + fragmentLayout.getLayoutParams().width);
    }

    private void init() {
        fragmentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout);
    }
```

Comment: You mean set the width and height in code or in the XML fragment tag?

Comment: Set the width and height in code. Or set the fragment layout width and height in code.

Comment: Have you tried using LayoutParams? After the View is inflated and added to the window, you can call getLayoutParams() which has 2 public variables (width/height) that you can set.

Comment: If i use getLayoutParams() my app crashes.. I edited my post so you can see how I inflate the layout in the fragment.